# Extract and display data from access table using VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, dao

I have a function to extract and then display a recordset in a listbox.

I only get one field in my listbox.

Is there a way I can display the whole column "Caption" (several fields) in the listbox?

```
Function GetCaption() As String

   Dim db As Database
   Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
   Dim SQL As String
   Dim LCaption As String

   Set db = CurrentDb()

   SQL = "SELECT Caption FROM tblMainMenu"

   Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)

   If rst.EOF = False Then
      LCaption = rst("Caption")
   Else
      LCaption = "Not found"
   End If

   rst.Close
   Set rst = Nothing

   GetCaption = LCaption

End Function

Private Sub btnGetCaption1_Click()

    LstBx.RowSourceType = "Value List"
    LstBx.RowSource = GetCaption

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

    LstBx.RowSource = ""
    btnGetCaption1.Caption = DLookup("ReportID", "tblMainMenu", "ReportID = 1")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how well I understand your goal.  But if you want the list box to contain `tblMainMenu.Caption` values, one per list box row, you can use the query as its Record Source.

With the form open in Design View, open the list box's property sheet, and select the Data tab.  Then choose "Table/Query" for Row Source Type.  Add this SQL for the Row Source property.

```
SELECT [Caption] FROM tblMainMenu
```

Then select the Format tab, and enter 1 for the Column Count property.

Finally switch to Form View and tell us whether that gives you what you want, or how it differs from what you want.